# Multiple Y axes in nvd3 scatter graph

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am plotting variables of two scales against time using         nvd3.js in scatter plot.
I would like to have 2 separate  axes for 2         y variables.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scatter plot doesn't support two y axes. You would have to modify the source code for that.

Comment: Can you give me any refences to do so? I have tried to edit Scatterplot.js with y1 and y2 axes but its not working.

Comment: There are no references or examples of that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: have created a fiddle of my edited Scatterplot.js here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/amithraj/LVWbd/)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the nvd3 sample of [multiChart](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/multiChart.html), if you only turn on stream4 and stream5, you get a scatter graph with multiple Y axes.
[image]